# Unable to call API from another class using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to call an API in `APICaller.java` from `MainActivity.java`. And then to put the data into recyclerview in `MainActivity.java`. However, it seems like it fails to call the API and `restaurantList` is empty. How can I go about to fix this? Thank you in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Restaurant> restaurantList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        restaurantList = new ArrayList<>();

        APICaller apiCaller = new APICaller();
        apiCaller.getRestaurants(new APICaller.OnRestaurantListReceivedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRestaurantListReceived(List<Restaurant> list) {
                 String name = list.get(0).toString();
                 PutDataIntoRecyclerView(list);
            }
        });
    }

    private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView (List<Restaurant> restaurantList) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, restaurantList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

APICaller.java

```
public class APICaller {
    private List<Restaurant> restaurantList;

    interface OnRestaurantListReceivedCallback{
        void onRestaurantListReceived(List<Restaurant> list);
    }

    public void getRestaurants(OnRestaurantListReceivedCallback callback){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example123.com/wp-json/wp/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        WordpressAPICall wordpressAPICall = retrofit.create(WordpressAPICall.class);
        Call<List<Restaurant>> call = wordpressAPICall.getData();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Restaurant>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Restaurant>> call, Response<List<Restaurant>> response) {
                List<Restaurant> restaurantModels = response.body();
                for(int i = 0; i < restaurantModels.size(); i++){
                    int id = restaurantModels.get(i).getId();
                    String title = restaurantModels.get(i).getTitle().getRendered();
                    restaurantList.add(restaurantModels.get(i));
                }
                callback.onRestaurantListReceived(restaurantList);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Restaurant>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ON FAILURE API CALL", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: That calls for  [Debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug).

Comment: `restaurantList` is empty because you never assigned anything to it .